# CSS3: nth child not working

Tags: html, css

My html is not working.I need to make the third paragraph have a font-size of 26px.Even thought i put the 4th child codeAcademy keeps saying that I did'nt give it a font size of 26 and that it is undefined

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 class="fancy">Hello<h3>
            <p class="fancy">Hello2</p>
            <p id="serious">hello3</p>
            <p>Hello4</p>
    </body>
 </html>
.fancy{
    font-family:Cursive;
    color: violet;
}
#serious{
    font-family:Courier;
    color:#8c8c8c;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: please add new question instead of editing an old one

Comment: That is what I was going to do but stack overflow does not allow me to add a question so i had to resort to changing this question.

Comment: well add some answers to improve your rep, if you do edits like this you will get even less rep, as for example you were hurting my rep right now

Comment: I've aided with some votes, hopefully you will be able to post other questions, but be careful and try to give back to the community with some answers to help avoiding this problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the h3 tag: **`</h3>`**

```
<h3 class="fancy">Hello</h3>
<p class="fancy">Hello2</p>
<p id="serious">hello3</p>
<p>Hello4</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4vcLqh9/